# Javascript: Jump to next enabled text box on [enter]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Forgive any bad coding.

I am trying to code a form where when the user hits 'Enter', and they are in one of the text boxes, they will proceed to the next text box instead of submitting the form.  I have a portion of code that works for this, except when one of the text boxes is disabled (attributes 'disabled' = 'disabled') it will simply stop and won't proceed past that.

I'd like it to skip over disabled text boxes, and move on to the next one.

This is my working code (that hits and sticks at the disabled text boxes).  I'm embarrassed to post the attempts that I've made to make this work :-|

```
    $('input').keydown(function (e) {
    var ae = document.activeElement; 
    if (
        ae.type != "button" &&
        ae.type != "submit" &&
        ae.type != "password" 
    )
    {
        var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
        if (key == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var inputs = $('form').find('input:visible');
            inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Typically the Enter key is for submitting a form and the Tab key is for navigating between input fields... breaking this convention would most likely just confuse users.

Comment: I think you want the `input:enabled` selector if your inputs are indeed disabled and not hidden. https://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/

Comment: Thanks Patrick:  My users are already confused.   This is a work around I coded to prevent them from early submits.   It's internal, so it's not something I'm exposing to the Internet.

Comment: To prevent early submits, use the [validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation). Not only will that solve your problem, it will conform to the convention and it will educate your users by giving visual feedback that they just attempted to submit the form by pressing the enter key. They'll eventually learn to stop doing that.

Comment: @richbai90 actually answered the question.   I changed the  "var inputs" line as follows.. 

     var inputs = $('form').find('input:visible:enabled');

and it works.    

Unfortunately, I don't know how to credit him with the answer.

Comment: Posted comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jquery solution to compliment @Nino Filiu

```
var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if (key == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputs = $('form').find('input:enabled'); //inputs are disabled not hidden
        inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
    }
```

The change is in `input:enabled` instead of `input:visible`. The latter will find any inputs that aren't hidden, the former will find any inputs that aren't disabled

Comment: Thanks @richbai90.   This works.   I also stacked the .find so it would move to the next 'visible' AND 'enabled' as follows..  

var inputs = $('form').find('input:visible:enabled');

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. No need for jQuery. I hope the code speaks for itself, but I'd be happy to explain it in details if needed.

Small addition to the OP's request, a suggestion by [Patrick Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541563/patrick-roberts), use `Shift+Enter` to jump to the previous input:

```js
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
const enabledInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input:enabled'));

inputs.forEach(elt => {
  elt.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
    if (evt.key=='Enter') {
      let currentInputIndex = enabledInputs.indexOf(elt);
      let nextInputIndex;
      if (evt.shiftKey) {
        nextInputIndex = (currentInputIndex-1)%enabledInputs.length;
      } else {
        nextInputIndex = (currentInputIndex+1)%enabledInputs.length;
      }
      enabledInputs[nextInputIndex].focus();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input>
<input>
<input disabled>
<input>
<input>
<input disabled>
<input>
<input>
```

Comment: For bonus points, make it cycle backwards if the shift key is held down :)

Comment: Should be `nextInputIndex = (currentInputIndex + enabledInputs.length - 1) % enabledInputs.length`